# Thunderbird: Show mails from sender - easy and fast

Tags: thunderbird

Imagine you read a mail from "Dr. Foo Bar".

Now you want to see all mails send from or to him.

How do you do this?

I only know the complicated way:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> search for mails in "from" (with annoying typing the mail address again)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> search for mails in "to"

Why is there not such an entry in the context menu of the mail sender?

Is there no easy to use way to jump from reading a mail from "Dr Foo Bar" to a list of all messages from/to him?

**Update**

Mails can be stored in different folders. Solutions which only work for one folder won't help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To search all emails in all folders, sent to or from a particular email address:

1. Right click on an email address and select "Copy Email Address"
2. Right click on the `[Search... <Ctrl+K>]` box [image: search box location] select Paste, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> or just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

However, you might not like Thunderbird's default search results view.

[image: Location of "Open email as list"]

If you prefer the view when you click on "Open email as list", shown below

[image: List view]

then the best solution is to install a Thunderbird plugin, which will make this the default.

1. From the menu select `Tools` > `Add-ons`
2. Type "search as" into the search box
3. Click the install button next to `Search as list 3.0`
4. Restart Thunderbird

Comment: In my preferences the global search was disabled. I enabled it now. It seems that this just works for mails which are indexed by thunderbird. I guess your solution works after thunderbird has indexed my folders.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider the [quicker quicksearch](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quicker-quicksearch/) add-on. It allows you to right-click on a message in the message list and immediately do a search in the quick search box for that sender's email address or domain. There are some things to note:

- The `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`H` keyboard shortcut doesn't work in some versions of Thunderbird.
- It includes the display name in the search, not just the email address.
- The domain search parses the address poorly, so you may end up with `example.com>` in the search box.
- You can't right-click on the sender address in the message panel; only right-clicking in the message list works.

That said, it does this one job pretty well in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy way to see both send from and to in a single window.

But you can easily sort by sender from your inbox view, just select an email from that person and click on the **From** header:

[image]

You can do the same in your "Sent" folder too.

Comment: +1 ... I had the same idea. Also you can simply type *sender*'s name for example I typed *Launchpad* and it showed all emails I got from Launchpad.

Comment: Mails can be stored in different folders. Solutions which only work for one folder won't help me. I guess your solution only works if all mails are in one folder. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @guettli Such queries are AFAIK only possible through the "search messages" window where you can ask to search in subfolders.

Comment: @SylvainPineau who is responsible for fixing usability problems like this?

Comment: @guettli http://www-archive.mozilla.org/support/thunderbird/bugs

Comment: I'd start by checking https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?product=Thunderbird&component=Search&resolution=---