# Alternative to Thunderbird which can search for to/cc/from easily

Tags: thunderbird, email, alternative

I tried to find a solution to search for all address headers (to/cc/from) in a simple user friendly way:

[Thunderbird: Show mails from sender - easy and fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643638/thunderbird-show-mails-from-sender-easy-and-fast)

Since there was no solution, I think about changing the mail client.

What alternative exist, which can show me all mails related to for example "foo@example.com"?

I think every mail address which gets displayed by the mail client should have a link to a search for all mails related to this address.

I store my mails on a own IMAP server.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your problem. When I search for an e-mail address with [Thunderbird's quick search bar](//i.stack.imgur.com/cvzc9.png), the search result includes e-mails with that address in the CC field.

Comment: I had quick search disabled before asking this question. Don't ask me why it was disabled. Still I search a way to get a similar result without quick search. I have some huge IMAP folders and indexing them takes very long.

Answer (score 8):

To find something suitable for you [go to this site](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/top-5-open-source-email-clients-for-linux).

I like Geary best:
[image: Geary]

To install it go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and copy-paste:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install geary
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of gmail. It can handle all your pop mails and as you know, google is pretty good with searches.

(+you don't loose your email when switching computers)

Comment: Is gmail a native GUI or just a webpage? Can I read mails in gmail while I am offline (not connected to the internet)?

Comment: Gmail is a website. However, you can use gmail offline plugin for browsers such as chrome.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative option would be no alternative.

I'm not aware of a one click option in any other email client.  They all require two similar steps to search all emails in all folders, sent to or from a particular email address.  For example, in Thunderbird:

1. Right click on an email address and select "Copy Email Address"
2. Right click on the `[Search... <Ctrl+K>]` box [image: search box location] select Paste, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> or just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

However, you might not like Thunderbird's default search results view.

[image: Location of "Open email as list"]

If you prefer the view when you click on "Open email as list", shown below

[image: List view]

then the best solution is to install a Thunderbird plugin, which will make this the default.

1. From the menu select `Tools` > `Add-ons`
2. Type "search as" into the search box
3. Click the install button next to `Search as list 3.0`
4. Restart Thunderbird